# How to load and run Intel-Tensorflow Model on ML.NET

Tags: python, tensorflow, ml.net, intel-tensorflow, intel-lpot

Environment: Tensorflow 2.4, Intel-Tensorflow 2.4

As far as I know, Tensorflow model in pb format can be loaded on ML.NET.

However, I'm using a quantization package LPOT (https://github.com/intel/lpot) which utilizes Intel optimized Tensorflow (https://github.com/Intel-tensorflow/tensorflow). Even though Intel-Tensorflow is built on Tensorflow, it uses some Quantized Op which has no registered OpKernel on Tensorflow (e.g. 'QuantizedMatmulWithBiasAndDequantize' is deprecated on TF). As a result, the quantized model cannot be run under native Tensorflow environment without installing Intel-Tensorflow.

My goal is to run this quantized pb Intel-Tensorflow model on ML.NET, does anyone know if Intel-Tensorflow is supported on ML.NET? Or is there any other way to do so?

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is supported but it may be best to add an issue to the ML.NET repository - https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues

Comment: @Jon Thanks, I will add an issue to their repo! I was just wondering if anyone had experience on this specific use case, as I couldn't find any resources/tutorials anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The oneDNN supported in ML.NET depends on the ML.NET integration. If they enable oneDNN in the TensorFlow C++ API, ML.NET could have oneDNN support.

[image]

You can try installing **stock Tensorflow 2.5** in your ML.NET environment with intel OneDNN enabled. You can install stock Tensorflow wheel from this link: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files

To install the wheel file: `pip install __.whl`.

To enable oneDNN optimizations, please set the environment variable TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS:

`set TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=1`

To ensure verbose log is displayed: `set DNNL_VERBOSE=1`

For more information on oneDNN verbose mode, please refer: https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneDNN/dev_guide_verbose.html

For more information on Intel Optimization for tensorflow, please refer: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Let me try to paraphrase it and please correct me if I'm wrong:
For instance, if I want to run on Windows platform, I should first install "tensorflow-2.5.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" in my ML.NET environment. Then in my code, I should set TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS = 1. This way, ML.NET is supposed to be able to run inference with my LPOT model. Is that correct?

Comment: I know there is Tensorflow.Net package that allows TF to run natively in ML.NET, I was wondering if I could make use of that package without having to install stock TF python wheel? One of the LPOT maintainers told me that ML.NET relys on https://www.nuget.org/packages/SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist/ and that I should try building new ML.Net source by specifying a new TF nuget package based on Intel Optimized TensorFlow (I have no idea what that means)